# Getting Crash - “Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10ec9b560) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10ec9b880)”

Tags: swift, types, objc-bridging-header

Am getting crash for data type conversion mismatch. how to change data type in swift to rectify this issue?

```
var Createsections: [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()
var TableData: [[String:Any]]   = [[String:Any]]()
```

for item in TableData {

```
 if let subcategories = item["subcategories"] as? [Any] {

    for item_list in subcategories {

             // item_list contain string value - Household
     Createsections.append(item_list as! [String: Any])// this line crash for me.
   }
```

}
}

I want to append that String Value into Createsections.

Comment: what type of data this list have item_list, seems item_list ist not dictionary

Comment: The error clearly states that `subcategories` is an array of strings (`[String]`). By the way never cast to `[Any]` if the actual type is more specific.

Comment: Thank you. i changed  array of strings [String] type. now i can append that string.